# How to get tx hash after tx was signed | Ethers js

Tags: web3js, ether, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When i run this code i get undefined logged in the console.

```
const send = async () => {
    const params = {
      from: App.currentAccount,
      to: recipient,
      value: amount,
      data: ethers.utils.hexlify(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(message))
    }
    const tx = await window.ethereum.request({method: "eth_sendTransaction", params: [params]})
    console.log(await tx.hash)
  }
```

once the transaction is signed it should show the tx hash so i can create a link to etherscan